# Mips 32 store sequential array to memory

Tags: memory, assembly, mips32

I am trying to store the numbers 0 to 10 sequentially in memory using mips32. Here is my code:

```
addi $s2, $zero, 10
addi $s1, $zero, 0
addi $t0, $zero, 0
addi $s6, $zero, 10
L1: 
  beq $s1, $s2, exit   
  sll $t0, $s1, 2           #multiply by the size of a word to get the cur address of $s6
  sw $t0, 0($s6)            
  addi $s1, $s1, 1
  j L1

exit:
```

I got an error with `sw $t0, 0($s6)` What is wrong with storing this at the beginning of memory?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running on bare metal, the OS (or the emulator) is providing virtual memory for your program. You don't typically get the whole address range assigned to your program, you need to ask the OS for blocks of memory - either via system calls or via the binary format itself, for example by reserving space in the `.bss` or the `.data` section.

PS.: The available address range rarely includes the first page, so that null pointers can be caught easily.